# How to create a Shiny app with input for predictor, displaying Shap plot and prediction?

Tags: r, machine-learning, shiny

I am trying to develop a Shiny app that allows users to input information for a predictor model. The predictor model is a Random Forest model trained on a dataset called dmstroke_web. Here's a snippet of the code used to train the model:

```
dmstroke_web <- dmstroke_web %>% 
  dplyr::select(status ,age ,sepsis, pneumonia ,
                hypertension , dyslipidemia , hypoalbuminemia , hypokalemia ,
                sex , chronic_ischemic_heart_disease ,
                anemia)

dmstroke_rf <- randomForest(status ~age +sepsis+ pneumonia +
                            hypertension + dyslipidemia +hypoalbuminemia + hypokalemia +
                            sex + chronic_ischemic_heart_disease +
                            anemia, data = dmstroke_web)
```

After training the model, I would like to create a Shiny app where users can input values for the predictor variables and then visualize the Shapley Additive Explanations (SHAP) plot along with the prediction made by the model.

Additionally, I have used the DALEX package to generate explanations for the model. Here's the code snippet for generating the explain_rf object:

```
explain_rf <- DALEX::explain(model = dmstroke_rf,  
                             data = dmstroke_web,
                             y = dmstroke_web$status == "dead", 
                             label = "Random Forest")
```

I have already successfully obtained the prediction and SHAP plot using the following code:

```
predict(explain_rf, henry)  
shap_henry <- predict_parts(explainer = explain_rf, 
                            new_observation = henry, 
                            type = "shap",
                            B = 25)
```

The predict function is used to obtain the prediction for a new observation named henry, while the predict_parts function generates the SHAP values for henry. These steps are working as expected.

Now, my goal is to integrate this functionality into a web-based application using Shiny. I want to create an interactive interface where users can input their own values, trigger the prediction and SHAP plot generation, and visualize the results dynamically within the Shiny app.

Any assistance or code examples that demonstrate how to achieve this integration using Shiny?